# Борьба с безграмотностью и этика

Tags: этикет

Вчера мне пришло по электронной почте одно письмо. То, что тон там был достаточно хамский, это не имеет значения и остается на совести отправившего. Но вот мимо того, что в письме размером в большой абзац не было ни одного знака препинания, кроме многочисленных многоточий, признаться, взбесило. И это я молчу о грамматических ошибках. Этот абзац мне пришлось расшифровывать минут пять, чтобы просто понять, что автор хотел сказать.
Не знаю, надо ли пропускать подобные ситуации? Я обычно делаю замечания в разной форме (зависит от того, к кому обращаюсь). В данной ситуации замечание было сделано в достаточно жесткой форме.
Как вы думаете, нужно ли закрывать глаза на такое или все-таки тыкать грамотеев в собственное безобразие? Ведь, если никто не будет их стыдить, они станут считать, что в издевательстве над родным языком ничего зазорного нет.
А как по-вашему?
Этот вопрос тут уже не раз понимался, но я снова хочу посоветоваться.
И в тему вопроса хорошая картинка:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно предположить такую ситуацию. У человека низкий уровень грамотности, но большое самомнение, что между собой сочетается плохо. Как выйти из положения? Можно стать нигилистом, то есть отрицать необходимость грамотного письма вообще: я пишу без знаков препинания, потому что не вижу в них необходимости по идейным соображениям.

Как с этим бороться? Думаю, что стыдить таких людей бесполезно, их надо высмеивать. Это, конечно, сложнее, но смех и ирония  всегда более эффективное оружие, чем простое увещевание.

Comment: Согласен, надо высмеивать. Как говорится, в приличном обществе таких бьют и унижают.

Answer (score 2):

Нужно ли делать замечание решать вам. Я скорее всего не буду. Мне приходится общаться с разными людьми и акцентирование внимания на граматике будет лишь мешать общению, по мне так хоть на польском пиши лишь бы понятно было. Если текст непонятен пускай расшифровывает сам. А вот если есть потребность закончить с каким-либо типом общение, да еще и унизив его напоследок, то можно и Розенталем по позициям противника ударить, но это почти ядерное оружие.

Answer (score 2):

Истина конкретна, как говорил Гегель, или, как сказал Иешуа, "истина в том, что у тебя болит голова", то есть все зависит от ситуации. Если человек работает с текстами, он должен писать грамотно, или он профнепригоден. Но если он сварщик... Глупо говорить врачу с плохим почерком: "Я не смог прочитать ваш рецепт, потому что у вас ужасный почерк. Потрудитесь освоить чистописание". Если ваша бабушка или мама напишет вам письмо с ошибками, вы вряд ли ответите им: "Ты пишешь безграмотно. Повтори правила пунктуации". Но когда мы получаем письмо от "плохого" человека, вдруг резко возрастает значение грамотности. Проанализируйте свои реакции в разных ситуациях и отследите двойные стандарты в своем поведении с учетом профессиональной потребности в грамотности.